# "This webpage is not available" from localhost after SSL removed

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, iis-7

When I attempt to debug my ASP.NET MVC 5 project I am getting the IIS error "This webpage is not available".  Here is the sequence of events that led to this:

- The project was originally using SSL and IIS Express and working fine.
- I wanted to use Fiddler and saw that Fiddler doesn't (easily) monitor **https** traffic, so went into the project properties (F4) tab and changed it back to use **http**.
- This is when I started seeing the error "The page can't be displayed".  I noticed that even though my ProjectUrl and Start URL in the project properties window was *http*://localhost:57505, when I debugged, the URL would change to *https*.
- A complication (sorry, I don't remember what it was) prompted me to use Local IIS (IIS 7.5) instead of IIS Express.
- I restarted IIS and I decided to get rid of the SSL certificate in IIS but that didn't help.
- Because nothing worked I changed the project back to use SSL.  Now I am seeing "This webpage is not available" when I debug.
- I have rebooted and recycled frequently

I'm not sure what to do next because my project is unusable right now.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you backing to using IIS Express?

Comment: Yes, I'm back to using IIS Express.

Comment: @Dewey when you click on the deployable project in Visual Studio, the Properties window should show the SSL URL and URL. What do those values say?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev, SSL URL = https://localhost:57505 and URL = http://localhost:57505

Comment: @Dewey what happens if you change the URL port from 57505 to 5700 or something.

Comment: OK, so now it's:  Project Url = http://localhost:5700;  Start Url = http://localhost:5700;  SSL Enabled = True; SSL URL = https://localhost:44300;  Url = http://localhost:5700;  In Fiddler I see a request to localhost:5700/.  In the browser I see a redirection to https://localhost/.  Nothing shows onscreen even though I should see the /Home/Index view content.

Comment: LATEST DEVELOPMENTS:  I moved the solution out of my git-hub folder and into a temp folder. I created a new solution in the git-hub folder.  (I want to continue to use the git-hub folder because I have GitHub configured for it.) I then moved everything from the old solution into the new folder except the solution file, the project files, and web.config. I wanted to keep those because they were created with the new, untainted solution. (BTW, there is only one project in the solution.) (MORE)

Comment: Everything should be the same as before in a new project that now has no association to https or SSL.  Looking in applicationhost.config I see the new project with only a http port, no https port.  Unfortunately when I start the project the result is the same.

Comment: Have u tried new virtual directory or Deploying to iiis in inetpub or from  from different location ?

Comment: Did you use HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to lock your site to HTTPS?

Answer (score 2):

Did you happen to had an entry in web.config that force a redirection to the HTTPS site?

```xml
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^account/logon$|^account/register$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Note that **redirectType="Permanent"**, it will return Permanent Redirect(301) to your browser. This will be cached permanently on your browser so you couldn't access the normal HTTP site even if you've removed this redirection.  You will need to manually clear your browser caches to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If it happens with other projects as well then try to disable windows firewall or any other firewalls on the system and hopefully it should work.

Also try to run the website without fiddler and see if it works.

I had similar problem and it was the firewall causing it.

Answer (score 0):

With HTTPS, you can only have one "web site" per `ip_address:port`. So https://localhost, https://example.com, it's all the same (modulo certificate errors.)

HTTP, however, allows multiple web sites per `ip_address:port` pair, via the "HOST" header in the HTTP 1.1 spec. IIS needs to know what site you want, and it defaults to binding the web site to the machine's hostname. (That is probably what is getting you.)

If you just want all requests that resolve to your host (like "localhost") to hit the same web site, edit the site bindings in `inetmgr` and set "Host Name" to empty string or `*`.